# Absolute values in linear programming

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose I have an objective function in my LP as follows

$max$  $|x|$

Based on some googling, I have found there are two ways to convert this into a standard LP.

**Method 1.**

$|x|$ = $ x^+ + x^-$

$x = x^+ - x^-$

$max$ $x^+ - x^-$

subject to

$x^+, x^- > 0$

**Method 2**
Since $|x| = max(x,-x)$, we introduce a new variable $t$ and rewrite the problem as

$max$ $t$

subject to

$t >= x$

My main question is are these 2 methods equivalent? Is one of them preferred over the other?
$t >= -x$

Answer (score 1):

If your objective function was a minimization problem, then the two methods would work and are equivalent.  For instance, consider a problem where $x=-2$.  Then, using method 2 for a minimization problem, you would have

$\begin{equation}
\text{min }t\\
t \geq 2\\
t \geq -2\\
\end{equation}
$

and the solution is 2.  Now try it with a max - the solution will be unbounded above.

However, you have a maximization problem.  Note that $|x|$ is a convex function. There is no LP reformulation of this problem.