# Linear programming (apply different multipliers for negative values )

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, absolute-value

The optimisation problem [PROBLEM 1]:
$$\max \sum_{t=T} x_t $$
subject to:
$$\ (1) x_t = (1+\alpha) x_{t-1}\     \forall t ..T$$ 
$$\  t=\{ 0..T\} , x_0= given$$ 
$$\ (e.g) x_1 = (1+\alpha) x_0\ $$ 
$$\ (e.g) x_2 = (1+\alpha) x_1\ $$ 
$$\ (e.g) x_3 = (1+\alpha) x_2\ $$

$$\   $$

$$\ (2) x_t \ge 0 $$

Now, I would like to allow negative value of the variable "x" and apply different factor. I made the following changes [PROBLEM 2]:

$$\ x_t =  x_t^+ -  x_t^-  $$

$$\ x_t = (1+\alpha) x_{t-1}^+  - (1+\beta) x_{t-1}^-  $$

$$\ x_t^+ , x_t^- \ge 0 $$

$$\ x_t \ge -10 $$

The solver gives infeasible(unbounded) solution! Is there an alternative way to solve such kind of problem, particularly, applying different factor (multiplier) for negative values. The model is more complex than what I wrote. But I wanted to just highlight on the problem.

Comment: where does the index $t$ come from?  what is index set

Comment: index t = {0..T} where T is the last time period.

Answer (score 0):

if $x_0$ is free, your problem is unbounded since. $\ x_t = (1+\alpha) x_{t-1}$ implies $\ x_t = (1+\alpha)^t x_0 $ so you can let $ x_0  \to + \infty $ .

if $x_0$ is given and fix then your feasible solution is singleton which is

$$\{ \bigl( x_0, ~  (1+\alpha) x_0, ~ (1+\alpha)^2 x_{0} ,..., ~    (1+\alpha)^T x_{0} \bigr)  \}$$

So your optimal solution is trivial . why need to solve problem !

Comment: x0 is given and the model is more complex but I wanted to just highlight on the problem. I included example of the constraints. The constraint you wrote is not correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need to introduce a binary variable $y_t$ for each value of $t$, signaling whether $x_t$ is positive or negative. The definition of $y_t$ would be handled by something like $$-My_t \le x_t \le M(1-y_t)$$ for some adequately large $M>0$. In this version, $y_t=0\implies x_t\ge 0$ and $y_t=1\implies x_t\le 0$. I can't write the $x_t$ : $x_{t+1}$ linkage without knowing the actual model, but it would involve multiple inequalities containing $y_t$.

Comment: we know always $x_t \ge 0 $.

Comment: Thanks prubin. I'll check if this works.
My goal is to solve problem 2. $$ x_t >= -10 $$ for problem 2: $$\ x_t^+ , x_t^- \ge 0 $$ as written above: $$\ x_t =  x_t^+ -  x_t^-  $$ I followed the model here in this Book in google "Tutorials on Emerging Methodologies and Applications in Operations Research. Presented at INFORMS 2004, Denver, CO" page 7-21. I understood from  holger3000 in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697384/absolute-values-in-linear-programming 
This models does not work with maximization problem. 
Do you suggest an alternative way how to solve this problem 2.

Comment: The comment by holger3000 was specific to objectives involving $|x_t|$. In your case, splitting into positive and negative parts by itself might not work regardless of whether you are maximizing or minimizing. That's why you need the extra binary variables I described. If you want to use them in conjunction with positive and negative parts, you add constraints $x_t^+\le M(1-y_t)$ and $x_t^- \le My_t$ for suitably large $M$.